C program question about array where max number of messages is checked of each student
Input

it will input a number n from user
it will input n number of numbers from user

I will give you a example of the process. User gives input:
4
2 0 0 1

it will print n-1 in first line then in next line. So now for processing take position so at 1st position we have 2 for 2nd position we have 0 for third position we have 0 for 4th position we have 1
we will go in chronological order.
At position 1 we have number 2 meaning 2 times so we pair position 1 two times with another position. the first non zero position in chronological order is position 4 which is 1 so we pair (position 1 and position 4), now once we are done pairing with non zero we will now pair it with a zero in chronological order so the closest is position 2 therefore we pair (position 1 and position 2), now position 4 has a non zero number that is 1 so meaning we pair it only once to the left over position that is position 3 therefore we pair (position 4 and position 3).
So output will be:
3
1 4
1 2
4 3

Code:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, i, j, num, pairs = 0;

    printf("Enter the value of n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int arr[n];

    printf("Enter the numbers:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    printf("%d\n", n - 1);

    i = 0;
    while (i < n) {
        num = arr[i];
        if (num > 0) {
            for (j = 0; j < num; j++) {
                // Pair with non-zero numbers first
                for (int k = i + 1; k < n; k++) {
                    if (arr[k] > 0) {
                        printf("%d %d\n", i + 1, k + 1);
                        arr[k]--;  // Decrement the paired number
                        pairs++;
                        break;  // Move to the next position
                    }
                }
                // Pair with zero numbers if non-zero pairs are exhausted
                if (j < num - 1 && pairs < n - 1) {
                    for (int k = i + 1; k < n; k++) {
                        if (arr[k] == 0) {
                            printf("%d %d\n", i + 1, k + 1);
                            pairs++;
                            break;  // Move to the next position
                        }
                    
                    }
                
                }
                
            }
            // Skip positions that have already been paired
            i += num;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


The above is the code I have upon inputing
4
2 0 0 1

I am getting
3
1 4
1 2

as output but not the last pair that is 4 3
another input I have tried
3
1 1 0

I am getting
2
1 2

as output but not the last pair that is 2 3
How can I find my error? I have attached the original question as screenshot. I am aware Stack Overflow is not a place to do homework but I have tried my best with code got it almost correct only 1 more line i am unable to solve.


Have you stepped through the code in a debugger to see where your idea of how the algorithm should work and how the code actually works are different?

Please do not copy+paste sections of your question to defeat the minimum length filter. This just creates additional work for editors. If the system asks you for more detail in your question, add something new.

I see at least three errors in the program.

arr[k]--;  // Decrement the paired number
While it's wise to mark a student as paired, doing it this way destroys the information how many messages he can send. You have to find another way for marking, also for zero-number students.
if (j < num - 1 && pairs < n - 1) {
Presumably you subtract 1 from num to account for the Pair with non-zero number, but it may be that such a pair wasn't found. I'd rather increment j for each pair and compare j < num.
for (j = 0; j < num; j++) {
j is incremented by 1 after each loop cycle, but it may be that two pairs were found.

